# 2h10 layover at PMI on early June, arriving from MUC, leaving for ALC. Is that enough time for connection?

Tags: layovers, short-connections, lufthansa, self-transfer, mallorca

MUC (Munich) -> PMI (Palma de Mallorca) -> ALC (Alicante)

So I'm trying to shave some euros off the cost of a trip to Munich this early June, and one option I'm pondering is getting a late (and maybe cheaper) Saturday flight back to ALC, instead of spending another 200+/night to stay at Munich until Sunday just to get up early and go straight to the airport.

The problem is that the only combination of flights I've found that doesn't force us to spend the night at the airport is a Lufthansa MUC-PMI + Vueling PMI-ALC combo where the MUC flight is arriving at PMI at 20:20, and the ALC flight is departing from PMI at just 22:30.

That leaves us barely above 2 hours to make the transfer.

These are independent flights, so we'll probably have to pick up our bags from the conveyor belt, go through security again, maybe even switch terminals. I've read that the MCT for this airport is 45 minutes, but I don't know e.g. how punctual Lufthansa is or whether the security queue on a Saturday evening on early June is longer than usual...

Is 2 hours enough time to switch between independent flights at Mallorca (Majorca) airport in early June?

Comment: I would say this is (very) risky, June is early peak season, Mallorca is a very busy airport, industrial action that has been affecting Lufthansa for several months now may not be resolved… [How long to allow for Connection Flights](https://www.palmaairport.info/flights/connection-flights/how-long-to-allow-for-connection-flights/). Allowing for gate closure your 2 hour window is actually more like 90 mins

Comment: Don't do it. It's very risky so you even if you make it, it will be nerve-racking.

Comment: Spending 200 for an extra night or `x` per ticket to get the next flight PMI->ALC <s>if</s> when something goes wrong. Which is cheaper?

Comment: @FreeMan I'm pretty sure I can get a cheaper room in my own country than in Munich, even at Majorca ;) but y'all are right that it's not worth the nervous breakdown if something goes even slightly wrong ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MCT is for **connecting** flights (where you usually stay airside, don't touch your bags, don't go to check-in...).

For a self-transfer 45 minutes would of course be completely impossible, as you need to get to the check-in desk before the check-in deadline for that flight, which is 40 minutes before departure!

Two hours is probably enough **if** (and that's a big if) everything is fine, i.e. no delays anywhere. Remember you have to:

- Deplane
- Get to baggage claim
- Wait for your bags (yawn, hope for you they're better than CDG)
- Find your way to departure
- Check-in before the deadline (remember, 40 minutes before scheduled departure)

After that you still need to:

- Go through security
- Get to your gate before the boarding deadline (20 minutes before scheduled departure).

Flights late in the day are more likely to have delays (as any delay during the day is likely to accumulate until that flight).

Remember that if you miss the check-in deadline for your second flight:

- You will be considered a no-show
- Your ticket is likely to be cancelled
- You will probably need to book and pay for a new flight, at your expense, at last minute prices (usually much more expensive)
- Since this is likely to be the last flight of the day, you will also have to book and pay for a hotel, at your expense, at last minute prices. You'll also have to cover transfers to/from the airport, meals, etc.

The usual rule of thumb for self-transfers is at least 4 hours, though it depends on the cost, frequency, appetite for risk, specific combination of flights, etc.

I honestly wouldn't bet much on that self-transfer. It's possible you make it, but you need to be aware of the consequences if you don't.

Comment: It seems rare for flights within Europe to arrive on time, especially on busy routes at busy airports in busy times. I'd definitely not expect to make it with checked baggage.